# Why did the Qax want to destroy the human race?

Tags: stephen-baxter

In *Timelike Infinity*, the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timelike_Infinity) plot summary states

> The future Qax takes two Spline ships … through the gate and on the journey reveals to Parz the reason behind its desire to completely destroy the human race.

I can’t find any other notes via Google to explain this detail. Can someone recall what the reason was?

Comment: That's what was going on before and during the time *the reason* was revealed.

Comment: *we saw them as a threat* seems more like the official party line touted all along, not a dark secret.

Answer (score 3):

The Qax wanted to destroy the humans because they blamed them for the destruction of the Qax homeworld in the original timeline.

The Qax homeworld was destroyed when they misfired on their own sun trying to destroy a human piloted Xeelee spacecraft.  If I recall correctly they were testing some aspect of Xeelee technology and naturally didn't want to risk a Qax life for that experiment.  Because those Qax traveled back in time, they decided that destroying humanity was the most direct way to protect their homeworld from eventually being destroyed.

I think this story is covered in a short-story, but I couldn't find it in [Vacuum Diagrams](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuum_Diagrams).  Maybe I missed it or its in the other Xeelee short story collections: [Resplendent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resplendent) or [Xeelee Endurance](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1473212715).

Also overtime the Qax nurtured and enhanced their hatred and contempt for mankind.  News of the (future?) destruction of their homeworld accelerated that.

Comment: I thought the destruction was due to a captive human tricking them; it was a response to their being occupied and happened long after the invasion.

Comment: Yes, it was a human captive that they loaded into a Xeelee starship.  When the human returned from his journey they were so freaked out they fired on the xeelee craft and accidently hit their own sun.  In Timelike Infinity, a Qax from post-homeworld destruction comes back from the future through the wormhole to take revenge and prevent humans from creating the conditions that destroy their world.